# PDI: how to combien IF and ISBLANK on formula step?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pdi

In my DB table, I have a column called `type` and its possible values are "A", "B" or Null.
If It's Null, I want to replace it to "C", otherwise no change.
So here's what I did on formula step:

```
IF(ISBLANK([type]);"C")
```

However I can an error message saying:  Please specify a Boolean type for field [type] as a result of formula [IF(ISBLANK([type]);"C")].

Where's the prob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things..

Correct formula for Null type is ISNA(), and yes you also forgot the ELSE part of the IF.

> IF(ISNA([type]);"C";[type])